# How to disable user preferences in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is it possible to disable user preferences in phpMyAdmin entirely? I know you can configure phpMyAdmin not to use a configuration table, but then user preferences are stored in the user's browser. I also know that one can disable certain preferences, but I would like to disable all of them and hide the Settings tab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not configurable; you'll have to edit libraries/Menu.class.php to hide the Settings menu tab and index.php to hide "More settings".

Answer (score -1):

use shell script command in console

```
mysql -> reset users
mysql -> create new user
```

set new user and password.
good luck

Comment: Not sure if you understood what my problem is. I want to disable the Settings tab in phpMyAdmin alltogether.